# How to save changes in a js file?

Tags: javascript, html

I got a task from school - I am a complete beginner when it comes to JavaScript. We got an instruction, but the instruction feels like it's missing some crucial parts. The task says:

Try to type following lines of code in the console
[examples]
And then write in the comments in a script.js file, what did the console return after each example.

They told us that we should open the file index.html in Chrome, and use the developers tools -> console. Okay, I get it. We got a directory with script.js and index.html. Content of index.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I am supposed to push all the files to GitHub later. In order to do so, I have to open and edit them. How do I open js files? In Atom? Or in Chrome console (and if it's on a console, then how do I save changes, comments etc)?

Comment: Yes, just use some standard text editor like Atom. No, the Chrome console is not useful here.

Comment: @Bergi well, Chrome does have that Workspaces thing, so you can edit files from within it. But I tried it once and wasn't impressed - I'd stick to a text editor.

Comment: If you really want to rough it up, you could even just use notepad. It's only comments anyway - pretty hard to screw up.

Comment: @vlaz file editing in chrome is meant for html/css changes, not js

Comment: @JoeyWood then I must be a wizard because I did it.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file(s) in Atom. To view the logs, use chrome

Comment: Okay, but when I open the js file in Atom, it's empty. Is it supposed to be like this. So whoever created this tasks just wants me to fill the js file with a comment on how the console reacted? Seems pretty odd to me to push a file with nothing but comments... I still don't get the dynamics between the console, js file and html file...

Comment: It sounds like a pretty introductory assignment trying to teach you how to pull and push to git as well as practicing basic js so wouldn't be too odd to just push comments.  Even though your console logs shouldn't be comments

Comment: @TenAwesomeYears I'm pretty sure you should put the js lines in there as well (possibly wrap them in `console.log`) so that you can execute the script using the html file you got

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your .html and .js file in any text editor. We mostly use Sublime Text, Atom and so on. But if you want to edit and save your files in Chrome Dev Tools:

*Open Dev Tools > Sources > Right Click and Add Folder to Workspace*

[image]